# How to check if a technical specification (TS) is available?

Tags: c++

A lot of new C++ features such as modules or concepts likely will not go in the next Standard C++17 but rather be a part of a [Technical Specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental).

How do we check if such a TS is available?
Is/will there be a standard way?

Comment: I think those technical specifications usually define a feature test macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Technical Specification has its own (set of) feature test macros.

As an example, the Filesystem TS ([n4100/2014](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4100.pdf?page=11#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A13%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C0%2C351%2C0%5D)) specifies the macro `__cpp_lib_experimental_filesystem` on the header `<experimental/filesystem>` for this:

> #### 5.2 Feature test macros [fs.req.macros]
>
> 2    Header `<experimental/filesystem>` shall supply the following macro definition:
>
> `#define __cpp_lib_experimental_filesystem 201406`

[p0096r5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0096r5.html#ts) has a nice colection of all such macros, for our convenience.

You may want to check beforehand for the necessary headers with `__has_include`, though.